# Preventing A Loop Inside Ajax.Complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Im trying to update a notification counter whenever an ajax call is submitted, i'd like to do this with ajax.complete - but im calling an ajax function inside of ajax.complete, which is obviously causing an endless loop.

What's a simple way to identify this specific ajax call to prevent it from triggering the ajax.complete action on itself.

I'm thinking of something like this below (apologies, I'm still learning all this).

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, request, settings) {
    if (event.data.name !== "NoRefresh"){
        $.ajax({
                url: "/Dashboard/UpdateCounter/",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "html",
                data: { name: "NoRefresh" }
        })
        .done(function (partialViewResult) {
            $("#updateme").text(partialViewResult);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Make sure your code is copied correctly. Your code as written here isn't even valid javascript.

Comment: Yeah i know, it's just an example of what im trying to do. I'm learning i want to set data (or something else) and then read it again when the complete method is called again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the jQuery docs:

> If `$.ajax()` or `$.ajaxSetup()` is called with the `global` option set to `false`, the `.ajaxComplete()` method will not fire.

So adding `global: false` to your inner `ajax` call will avoid the infinite loop.

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, request, settings) {
    $.ajax({
            url: "/Dashboard/UpdateCounter/",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "html",
            data: { name: "NoRefresh" },
            global: false 
    }).done(function (partialViewResult) {
        $("#updateme").text(partialViewResult);
    });
});
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what i was looking for. Thanks